# Can't update xml with non-latin characters in Oracle

Tags: java, xml, oracle, plsql, clob

I have a Java application where I store data in clob and then I use UPDATEXML to update. It works perfectly on latin characters, symbols. But I come from Georgia and it won't update Georgian letters (აბგ). I tried with Russian letters and it worked perfectly.

```
select = "update datadocumentxml d\n" +
                    "   set d.datadocumentxml = updatexml(xmltype(d.datadocumentxml),'/Comments/@Comment, ?)\n" + 
                    "                                   .getClobVal(),\n" + 

                    " where d.processengineguid = fnguidjava2raw(?)\n" + 
                    "   and d.datadocumentid = 'Comments'";
        ps = conn.prepareStatement(select);

        ps.setClob(1,clob);
        ps.setString(2,processid);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

This is my update statement, when I try to update Georgian letters, I get different errors:

```
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: No more data to read from socket
```

I suppose it has something to do with encoding.. any ideas?

Comment: What are your DB and application character sets? That error usually means you (or your DBA) can find details of what really went wrong in the server's alert log, so digging that out will be helpful. Not sure if it's relevant but you seem to be missing a closing single quote for `'/Comments/@Comment` ?

Comment: that was just a typo, I do succeed in updating English characters, the only problem I have is with Georgian ones. I have to look up the character sets I don't know what they mean sorry