# Error updating CLOB in oracle : ORA-00600: internal error code

Tags: java, xml, oracle, clob

I am trying to update my xml using a clob. I have no problem updating English characters. I can even update Russian and Arabic. but when it comes to Georgian characters, I get this internal error.

this is the update:

```
select = "update datadocumentxml d\n" +
            "   set d.datadocumentxml = updatexml(xmltype(d.datadocumentxml),'/Comments/@Comment', ?)\n" + 
            "                                   .getClobVal(),\n" + 

            " where d.processengineguid = fnguidjava2raw(?)\n" + 
            "   and d.datadocumentid = 'Comments'";
ps = conn.prepareStatement(select);

ps.setClob(1,clob);
ps.setString(2,processid);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

this is the error I get when trying to update Georgian letters:

```
   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00600: internal error code, 
arguments: [17114], [0x7FEA96179698], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17114], [0x7FEA96179698], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3657)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor845.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyFactory.invoke(PreparedStatementProxyFactory.java:125)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy949.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at ge.bog.integration.crif.data.collector.connector.parallelcomments.UpdateXml.setComment(UpdateXml.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at ge.bog.integration.crif.data.collector.core.ProcessorImpl.executeClassFunction(ProcessorImpl.java:67)
... 46 more
```

I think it has something to do with charsets or JDBC driver. any suggestion would be much appreciated.

this is a wiki page for Georgian characters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgian_(Unicode_block)

Comment: Looks like you are running into an Oracle Bug. Check the Oracle support site.

Comment: ORA-00600 errors are unhandled Oracle exceptions i.e. bugs. The only assured way of resolving them is to contact Oracle Support, as they usually require a patch or similar low level fix. If your organisation doesn't pay for a Support contract you're probably out of luck. A quick search of the internet uncovers [many and various causes of this problem](https://www.bing.com/search?q=ora-00600+17114).

Comment: You can edit a question if you want to add something, you don't need to post it again. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55611453/cant-update-clob-with-foreign-characters-using-updatexml-in-java

Comment: [And this one...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55515523/266304)